# ValueError: Cannot assign "'Category'": "Course.category" must be a "Category" instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have a problem when I trying to run my unit tests.
Why does it give me that error message?

Code from tests.py:

```
class CourseTestCase(TestCase):
    def create_category(name="English", imgpath="ImgPath"):
        return Category.objects.create(name=name, imgpath=imgpath)

    def setUp(self):
        Course.objects.create(
            name='English',
            description='Sample text',
            category_id=self.create_category().id,
            logo='Logo'
        )

    def test_course_category(self):
        english = Course.objects.get(name='English')
        self.assertEqual(english.category_id, 1)
```

Models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    imgpath = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    logo = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

> ValueError: Cannot assign "'Category'": "Course.category" must be a "Category" instance.

Comment: Can you share your models.py?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just added - models.py, the code below couldn't help me(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code

```
class CourseTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.category = Category.objects.create(name="English", imgpath="ImgPath")
        self.course = Course.objects.create(
            name='English',
            description='Sample text',
            category=self.category,
            logo='Logo'
        )

    def test_course_category(self):
        english = Course.objects.get(name='English')
        self.assertEqual(english.category_id, self.category.id)
```

Comment: Just added - models.py, the code below couldn't help me(

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```py
category_id=self.create_category().id,
```

to this:

```py
category=self.create_category(),
```

The error `ValueError: Cannot assign "'Category'": "Course.category" must be a "Category" instance.` is telling you that the attribute `category` are expecting a class instance of `Category` and not his `id`

Comment: Then the problem isn't in this code. Maybe the full traceback could help.